# Как прибавить +1 к числовому содержимому HTML элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<a class="r3e lk3" id="269" href="#" rel="nofollow"><span class="lk5">235</span></a>
```

есть вот в каждом комментарии такая ссылка,при нажатии которой отправляется post запрос следующим кодом

```
<script>
    jQuery('a.r3e').on('click',function () {

var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

$.ajax({
url:"/api/reviews/uplike/",
method: "POST",
data: ({ id: id }), //отправляем постом id элемента
beforeSend: function(data) {
// выводим диалоговое окно о том что лайк проставляется
alert('ставим лайк');
},

complete: function(data) {
// лайк успешно поставлен, запрос post передан

alert('спасибо за активность на сайте');
}

});


return false;

});
</script>
```

как мне этим же яваскриптом к цифре 235 добавить +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  jQuery('a.r3e').on('click',function () {

 var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

 $.ajax({
 url:"/api/reviews/uplike/",
 method: "POST",
 data: ({ id: id }), //отправляем постом id элемента
 beforeSend: function(data) {
 // выводим диалоговое окно о том что лайк проставляется
 alert('ставим лайк');
 },

 complete: function(data) {
 // лайк успешно поставлен, запрос post передан
 let elem = document.getElementById('269');
 elem.innerHTML++       //------------------ HERE//
 alert('спасибо за активность на сайте');
 }

 });


 return false;

 });
```